# Angular deployement in dev or production using Jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

In jenkins , how angular app will be deployed using "ng build --prod" command? How we can point dist folder to load the application in production or dev server? In local we do only "ng serve" for building. If we want to do ng build -- prod in local, will we be able to produce the same process which is followed in production or dev deployment?

Comment: To run an angular application in production is not recommended with "ng serve". 
"ng build --prod" - will generate a production-based deployable, which you need to deploy on an HTTP server like apache-httpd, nginx. 
if you are interested to do the deployment in cloud there are many ways from many cloud provider.

Comment: Is using "ng build -- prod"enough? How dist folder can be taken and run in the browser? Any code change required for this in angular or just we need to do configuration changes in jenkins?

Comment: as I said once you have the dist folder, you can copy and paste that to an httpd or nginx server, then by using the host and port of that server you can access your website. There are many articles you can find on the internet.
but from CI/CD you can use the command-line tool to copy your dist folder into the HTTP server folder.